# Increasing Memory when use CGImageRef and CGContextRef in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Whenever this method call it increase the size of the memory. How to stop the increasing of memory size?

```
static unsigned char *RequestImagePixelData(UIImage *inImage) 
{
    CGImageRef img = [inImage CGImage]; 
    CGSize size = [inImage size];
    CGContextRef cgctx = CreateRGBABitmapContext(img); 
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{size.width, size.height}};
    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, img);
    unsigned char *data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
    CGContextRelease(cgctx);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: when  this method "RequestImagePixelData" start execution, in fifth line its increase the size of the memory e.g. memory size 76.1 MB becomes 78.0 MB

Comment: OK, and what is your question ?

Comment: My question is, how to stop the increasing of memory size

Comment: OK, please hit the `edit` link above and add the above information to your question so that people will know what you are asking.

Comment: Try placing your code inside @autoreleasepool {
    ...do your work here...
  }

Comment: @autoreleasepool not working in this code. still increasing the size